# Installing MySQL 5.6 in Ubuntu 14.04 triggers removal of needed packages

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, kde-plasma, mysql-5.6

So I was trying to make a fresh installation of MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and for some reason it tried to remove needed packages, not without first complaining about some unmet dependencies. Here's what happened:

```
pedro@hope:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>= 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
pedro@hope:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-core-5.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
pedro@hope:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl advancecomp amor analitza-common ark astrometry.net audiocd-kio
  avogadro-data blinken bomber bovo cantor cantor-backend-kalgebra cervisia
  chemical-mime-data dirmngr dnsmasq-base docbook-to-man dragonplayer edict
  filelight fonts-dustin freerdp-x11 freespacenotifier gnugo granatier
  gwenview iputils-arping juk kaccessible kalgebra kalgebra-common kalzium
  kalzium-data kamera kanagram kanjidic kapman kapptemplate kate katomic
  kblackbox kblocks kbounce kbreakout kbruch kcachegrind kcalc kcharselect
  kcolorchooser kcron kde-artwork-active kde-base-artwork kde-baseapps
  kde-config-cddb kde-config-cron kde-icons-mono kde-style-oxygen
  kde-wallpapers kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager
  kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins
  kde-zeroconf kdeaccessibility kdeadmin kdeartwork-emoticons kdeartwork-style
  kdeartwork-theme-window kdeedu kdeedu-kvtml-data kdegames-card-data
  kdegames-data kdegames-mahjongg-data kdegraphics kdegraphics-mobipocket
  kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdegraphics-thumbnailers kdemultimedia
  kdenetwork-filesharing kdenetwork-strigi-analyzers kdepasswd
  kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesdk kdesdk-kio-plugins kdesdk-misc kdesdk-scripts
  kdesdk-strigi-plugins kdesdk-thumbnailers kdetoys kdewallpapers kdf kdiamond
  kdm kfilereplace kfourinline kgamma kgeography kgeography-data kget
  kgoldrunner khangman khelpcenter4 kig kigo killbots kimagemapeditor
  kinfocenter kio-audiocd kiriki kiten kjumpingcube klettres klettres-data
  klickety klines klipper kmag kmahjongg kmenuedit kmines kmix kmousetool
  kmplot kmtrace knavalbattle knetwalk kolf kollision kolourpaint4 kommander
  kompare konquest kpartloader kpat krdc kremotecontrol kreversi krfb
  krosspython kruler ksaneplugin kscd kshisen ksirk ksnakeduel ksnapshot
  kspaceduel ksplash-theme-active ksquares kstars kstars-data ksudoku
  ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog kteatime ktimer ktimetracker ktouch
  ktouch-data ktuberling kturtle ktux kubrick kuiviewer kuser kwalletmanager
  kwordquiz kwrite libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt1 libakonadi-calendar4
  libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4
  libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadi-socialutils4
  libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libanalitza5abi1 libanalitzagui5abi1
  libanalitzaplot5abi1 libao-common libao4 libapr1 libaprutil1 libastro1
  libavogadro1 libbaloopim4 libblas3 libbluetooth3
  libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0
  libboost-thread1.54.0 libcfitsio3 libcln6 libcomposereditorng4
  libdeclarative-multimedia libdiscid0 libdmtx0a libegl1-mesa
  libegl1-mesa-drivers libelfg0 libexif12 libexttextcat-data
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libftdi1 libgadu3 libgbm1
  libgfortran3 libgl2ps0 libglamor0 libgle3 libgles2-mesa libglew1.10
  libglib2.0-bin libgpgme++2 libgpgme11 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n
  libgphoto2-port10 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libgrantlee-gui0 libgsl0ldbl
  libical1 libieee1284-3 libindi-data libindi0c libindicate-qt1 libindicate5
  libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libkabc4 libkalarmcal2
  libkasten2controllers2abi1 libkasten2core2 libkasten2gui2
  libkasten2okteta1controllers1abi1 libkasten2okteta1core1
  libkasten2okteta1gui1 libkateinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4
  libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw23
  libkdecorations4abi1 libkdeedu-data libkdegames6 libkdgantt2-0
  libkeduvocdocument4 libkephal4abi1 libkfbapi1 libkgapi2-2 libkholidays4
  libkimap4 libkipi-data libkipi11 libkiten4abi1 libkldap4 libkleo4
  libkmahjongglib4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4
  libkolab0 libkolabxml1 libkomparediff2-4 libkontactinterface4 libkpgp4
  libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkresources4 libkrossui4
  libksane-data libksane0 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4
  libksignalplotter4 libktnef4 libktorrent5 libkunitconversion4
  libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglesutils1 libkwinglutils1abi3 libkworkspace4abi2
  liblapack3 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblightdm-qt-3-0 liblircclient0
  libmailtransport4 libmarblewidget18 libmariadbclient18 libmbim-glib0
  libmeanwhile1 libmediastreamer-base3 libmicroblog4 libmm-glib0 libmms0
  libmnl0 libmodemmanagerqt1 libmsn0.3 libmtdev1 libmusicbrainz3-6
  libmusicbrainz5-0 libneon27-gnutls libnepomukdatamodel0
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnetworkmanagerqt1 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4
  libnm-util2 libnova-0.14-0 liboath0 libokteta1core1 libokteta1gui1
  libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenbabel4 libopenconnect2 libopenvg1-mesa
  libortp9 libotr5 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasmaclock4abi4
  libplasmagenericshell4 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a
  libqaccessibilityclient0 libqalculate5 libqalculate5-data libqextserialport1
  libqgpgme1 libqhull6 libqmi-glib0 libqoauth1 libqrencode3 libqt4-help
  libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtlocation1
  libqtmultimediakit1 libqtwebkit-qmlwebkitplugin libquazip0 libraw9 libsane
  libsane-common libsendlater4 libsensors4 libserf-1-1 libshp1 libsignon-qt1
  libsp1c2 libspandsp2 libspice-server1 libsrtp0 libsvn1 libswscale2
  libsyndication4 libtaskmanager4abi5 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libupnp6
  libvncserver0 libwayland-client0 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwayland-server0
  libwcs4 libweather-ion6 libwlocate0 libxatracker2 libxcb-composite0
  libxcb-damage0 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xtest0
  libxerces-c3.1 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxvmc1 lightdm
  lightdm-kde-greeter lirc lokalize lskat marble marble-data marble-plugins
  mariadb-common mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager
  mysql-server-core-5.5 network-manager network-manager-pptp okteta optipng
  oxygen-cursor-theme p7zip-full palapeli palapeli-data parley parley-data
  picmi pkg-kde-tools plasma-active-data plasma-active-metadatamodels
  plasma-active-mobilecomponents plasma-active-settings
  plasma-active-webbrowser plasma-containments-addons
  plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktopthemes-artwork plasma-nm
  plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba plasma-widget-folderview
  plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement
  plasma-widgets-active poxml pptp-linux python-avogadro python-beautifulsoup
  python-dateutil python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-enchant python-gi
  python-iniparse python-levenshtein python-numpy python-pyfits python-qt4
  python-qt4-sql python-simplejson python-sip python-utidylib python-vobject
  qhull-bin qtdeclarative4-kqtquickcharts-1 rocs setserial share-like-connect
  share-like-connect-data sp startactive-data step subversion svgpart sweeper
  systemsettings texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc translate-toolkit
  ttf-sjfonts umbrello unzip update-notifier-kde usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data valgrind vorbis-tools x11-xkb-utils xfonts-base
  xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl
  xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod xserver-common
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware zip
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt4-declarative-gestures
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akonadiconsole akregator blogilo
  kaddressbook kajongg kalarm kde-config-pimactivity kde-full
  kde-plasma-desktop kde-plasma-netbook kde-standard kde-workspace
  kde-workspace-bin kdeartwork kdegames kdenetwork kdepim kdepim-kresources
  kdepim-runtime kdeplasma-addons kdeutils kdewebdev kgpg kjots kleopatra
  klinkstatus kmail knode knotes konsolekalendar kontact kopete
  kopete-message-indicator korganizer kscreensaver kscreensaver-xsavers
  libcalendarsupport4 libeventviews4 libincidenceeditorsng4 libkdepim4
  libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkopete4 libksieveui4 libmailcommon4
  libmailimporter4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4
  libmessageviewer4 libnoteshared4 libpimactivity4 libpimcommon4
  libtemplateparser4 mysql-client-core-5.5 plasma-dataengines-workspace
  plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-runners-addons plasma-wallpapers-addons
  plasma-widget-lancelot plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace
  python-kde4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt4-declarative-gestures mysql-client-core-5.6
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 65 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,102 kB of archives.
After this operation, 125 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Some extra information, in case it helps:

```
pedro@hope:~$ uname -a
Linux hope 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

KDE SC Version: 4.13.2
```

Am I missing something? This happened both with the existing MySQL 5.6 version in the repositories and the ones in ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6. I also followed [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/), but the result was the same (trying to remove necessary packages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/akonadi/+bug/1330180) in `akonadi-backend-mysql 1.12.1-0ubuntu1`.
I just added [ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/kubuntu-ppa_backports) repository with this bug fixed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After this I installed `mysql-server-5.6` successfully.